# Stop test execution of testNG if data provider is empty

Tags: automated-tests, testng

hi I want to stop further test execution when there is no data in dataprovider. My dataproviders get filled up dynamically on the fly. So i want my tests to stop from execution if there is not data in dataprovider. Below is my code snippet.

```
package myTest;

import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest
{
    String str;
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] test123()
    {
        System.out.println(" Filling dataprovider.");
        return new Object[][]{};
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider="test123")
    public NewTest(String str)
    {
        System.out.println("Running through factory.");
        this.str=str;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1234()
    {
        Reporter.log("--->>> running test "+str,true);
    }
}
```

I want that test1234 should not run if dataprovider is empty.

Comment: did you run the test?, I think testNG takes care of this automatically and won't run your test, if your test doesn't take any parameter and you are passing empty dataProvider to it.

Comment: Yeah i ran above test and it generated all the reports and all. that's what i don't want to get generated. so the problem is i have huge number of tests and it becomes difficult to go through each report and see whether that test has run or not. so i want that if there is no test data then no report should get generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding another method in different class and add Factory 
annotation on that. From this method you can call the constructor of this Test Class in order to execute the tests. Before calling the constructor, check if the argument is correct and you actually want to run the tests for this argument. Now you need to call this Factory class.

```
<code>

Class NewTestFactory(){

@Factory(dataProvider="test123")    
public Object[] executeTests(String str){
Object obj[] = new Object[1];

        if (str != null){
        obj[0] = new NewTest(str)
        }
    }
  return obj
}

</code>
```

Comment: hi neeraj.. in TestNG..the dataprovider is only available when the test instance is run in case of factory provision. so if we try to use above method, we would not be knowing if the dataprovider for that test instance has value or not.

Comment: Sorry to mention that you can put ur data provider in the same class where you going to put the Factory method. I believe data provider is getting used by only the Factory which is further passing the parameter to the test class instance. If thats the case, it should work fine if you extract out the factory and data provider in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return an empty 2D array.
Something like:

```
 @DataProvider
    public Object[][] test123()
    {
        Object[][] data= null;
        System.out.println(" Filling dataprovider.");
        if(someSplCondition) //Returning empty 2D so that test doesn't execute
             data =  Object[0][0]
        else
             data = fillTestData()

        return data;
    }
```

Also, if you are using maven don't forget to put -DfailIfNoTests=false in mvn command

Comment: if you would notice thats what i do..return empty 2D object array..but it still goes ahead and executes test method and generates reports